# change html value of class

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i'm trying to do is to change the value of a specific column by jQuery. I only know the name of the column, but the position of the column is not always the same.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4MJjU/

This code is working, but is this the best way to check and to change the value?

```
var IDcolumns = document.getElementsByClassName('column-'+positionID); 
  for (i=0;i<IDcolumns.length;i++) 
  { 
      switch(IDcolumns[i].innerHTML){
      case "yes":
            //Just as example: 
            $(IDcolumns[i]).html('<img src="image.png" />');
            break;
      case "no": 
            $(IDcolumns[i]).html('&nbsp;');
            break;
  }
}
```

The other code in jsfiddle (show/hide columns) is for something else.

Comment: If you are going to use Jquery at all, you might as well use it for everything. It will reduce the code size and simplify it

Comment: Cant you add a specific class when you are setting the innerHTML. and for that specific class, set the innerHTML()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to address this depending on the HTML structure.

Following your example you could do something as simple as this:

```
$('.column-'+positionID + ':contains("yes")').html('<img src="image.png" />');
$('.column-'+positionID + ':contains("no")').html('&nbsp;');
```

[:Contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) will match if the cell contains the text (ignoring whitespace and other text).

Comment: I suppose this will be faster than the each-function?

Comment: This is really nice and faster than .each, I like it :). But this may fail if any value contains yes/no and user want strictly check yes/no only. After all this depends on user requirement, but this is really nice.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar what do you mean with "But this may fail if any value has yes/no and user want strictly check yes/no only"?

Comment: @endeka: Possibly but you are worrying about small speed differences in a situation that runs infrequently. Just make sure your needs are met simply then worry about the speed *if it is too slow*.

Comment: He means that, as I mentioned , this is a partial text match. If the cell contain "yes please" it would also match "yes"

Comment: @endeka, suppose your requirement is replace image when value equal to 'yes' and not when value equal to 'yes I know' (just example), then in this case it will fail. yes, TrueBlueAussie is correct.

Comment: oh ok, but that is not a problem. the yes/no comes from a choice field. So I"m 100% sure of the values. Tnx for the help!

Comment: @endeka, in your case it will surely work. Thats why I said it depends on requirement and incoming data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a jQuery here :

```
$('.column-'+positionID).each(function{
    var html = $(this).html();
    if(html == "yes")
      $(this).html('<img src="image.png" />');
    else if(html == "no")
      $(this).html('&nbsp;'); 
});
```

Comment: Avoid re-querying the same element in jQuery `$(this)` where you can. Use a temp var.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Tnx for the code. After some edits it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/4MJjU/1/. But I've read that the each-function is not the fastest solution?